# Why is num not showing the correct value?

Tags: react-native, iterator, react-native-flatlist

I am learning React-Native and building a game as a first app. I am building a flatlist of buttons based on a JSON fetch of results. The title of the button should be a number, ideally stating at 1,...n up to the n number of results. My test data set is 5.

I have tried not incrementing num, where all I see is '0' for all buttons. I have tried num--, where I see -5, -6,-7,-8 etc.

```
        <View style={styles.board}>
          <FlatList   
            data={this.state.data} 
            keyExtractor={(x, i) => i.toString()} 

            // renderItem is a FlatList prop
            renderItem={({ item }) =>
            <View style={styles.answers}>

              <Button               
                title = {`${num++}`} // POINT OF CONTENTION
                onPress={() => {
                  Alert.alert(
                    'Answer', // dialog title
                    `${item.name.first} ${item.name.last}`, // dialog message
                    [
                      {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'), style: 'cancel'},
                      {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')},
                    ],
                    //{ cancelable: false } // disables the option to cancel
                  )
                }}                
              />
              </View>
              }                       
          /> 
        </View>
```

Expected behaviour: Numbers 1,2,3,4,5 show up.
Actual behaviour: 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following,

```
<View style={styles.board}>
          <FlatList   
            data={this.state.data} 
            keyExtractor={(x, i) => i.toString()} 

            // renderItem is a FlatList prop
            renderItem={({ item, index }) =>
            <View style={styles.answers}>

              <Button               
                title = {index+1} // POINT OF CONTENTION
                onPress={() => {
                  Alert.alert(
                    'Answer', // dialog title
                    `${item.name.first} ${item.name.last}`, // dialog message
                    [
                      {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'), style: 'cancel'},
                      {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')},
                    ],
                    //{ cancelable: false } // disables the option to cancel
                  )
                }}                
              />
              </View>
              }                       
          /> 
        </View>
```